# OpenGL ES 2.0 shader uniform variables behaving unexpected

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, shader

I'm using libGDX for Android development, testing largely on desktop. I have a shader that is working exactly as expected there, but on Android, some uniform variables appear incorrect and inconsistent. Some assertions indicate that they are correctly sent to the shader, while some contradict this and indicate that they aren't.

Parts of the fragment shader:

```
uniform int L;
uniform vec2 center[10];

[...]

for (int i = 0; i != L; i++)
{
    if (i == 0 && center[0].x > 2.0)
    {
        color.b = 1.0;
    }
    if (center[i].x > 2.0)
    {
        color.g = 1.0;
    }
    [...]
}
[...]
```

The program enters the first if statement but not the second, rendering the screen blue. (On my desktop, it correctly renders cyan.) What's more, if I leave the app using the Home button and then resume it, it renders the screen RED, even though I never set And the result of the real rendering code (not shown here) looks as if all coordinates in the `center` array are uninitialized positions at (0; 0).

And `L` acts bit strange as well - when the loop condition was `i < L` instead of `i != L`, the phone seemed to take way too many iterations in the loop. (`i < 3` resulted in 3 iterations, but `i < L`with `L == 3` didn't.)

For sending the array, these are the ways I have tried:

```
shader.setUniform2fv("center[0]", new float[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3}, 0, 8);
shader.setUniformf("center[0]", 7, 8);
shader.setUniform2fv("center", new float[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3}, 0, 8);
shader.setUniform2fv(shader.fetchUniformLocation("center[0]", true), new float[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3}, 0, 8);
shader.setUniformf(shader.fetchUniformLocation("center[0]", true), 7, 8);
shader.setUniform2fv(shader.fetchUniformLocation("center", true), new float[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3}, 0, 8);
```

I tried each one seperately, the result was always the same. (I couldn't even push a single Vector2 separately with the `uniformf` calls - 2nd and 5th line here.)

### Complete, mostly minimal example

While reducing the code, it started to behave strange on the desktop as well. The reduced fragment shader (vertex shader is the default):

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec4 pos;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

uniform vec2 center[4];

void main() {
    vec2 worldCoord = vec2(0);
    vec3 color = vec3(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 && center[0].x > 2.0)
        {
            color.b = 1.0;
        }
        if (center[i].x > 2.0)
        {
            color.g = 1.0;
        }
        color.r = 0.0001 * distance(worldCoord, center[i]);
        color += vec3(distance(worldCoord, center[i]),0,0);
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0) * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```

Sending the array from Java code:

```
shader.setUniform2fv(shader.fetchUniformLocation("center[0]", true), new float[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3}, 0, 8);
```

Behavior on desktop:

- When I render a white rect to the screen, this makes it
  yellow - the second if clause is entered without the first.
- If I remove any (or both) of the two "red-modifying" lines, the first one is
  entered as well (screen cyan/white).
- Before removing other uniform parameters, worldCoord was the coordinate of the fragment in the units of the game (calculated for each one from the world size, viewport size and fragment position). The if clauses acted the same, but the red channel was 0 for the entire screen - apparently the distance function returned 0. (Screen green)

Comment: For GLSL ES you can't have a variable loop size. The number of operations must be known at compile time. Also try to avoid branching.

Comment: Thanks, that does explain the loop behavior. The contradictory asserts still remain after changing it to `i < 4`, though. (As for branching, I only added it during debugging, the actual rendering code doesn't have any.)

Comment: You didn't provide enough information, but that's probably because of the array. Use `ShaderProgram#fetchUniformLocation` instead of `getUniformLocation` and if needed, include the index, e.g. `fetchUniformLocation("center[0]");`.

Comment: Tried using `fetchUniformLocation()`, no avail. Added every `setUniform` call I've tried using to the question.

Comment: I managed to reduce the problem to a complete readable example. Is it answerable now?